# How to change a terraform variable depending on runtime information?

Tags: terraform, cloud-init, hashicorp

I have a Terraform script that, after creating several nodes, installs a piece of software on them by telling one node about the other ones using cloud-init. I want this cloud-init piece to only run when this one node is initially created, and not if it's altered or re-created. Now thanks to Terraform plan, Terraform has the information needed, it's telling the user clearly if the node has to be re-created or if it's created the first time at all. But how do I get this kinda information in my script?

The (boring) and manual way is of course to make it a variable that a human enters after reviewing the plan. But this is hardly scalable, secure or sophisticated.

Maybe Terraform is entirely the wrong tool for this kinda job?

Answer (score 1):

Terraform does not expose the information about what action is planned for an object for use in the configuration itself, because Terraform is a desired state system and so the actions are derived from the configuration, rather than the configuration being derived from the actions.

To achieve what you described I think you'll need to arrange for the initialization process to itself remember that it already run in some persistent location. Cloud-init itself remembers when it has run to completion so that rebooting the system won't re-run initialization tasks, but of course that information cannot survive replacing the VM entirely and so you'd need to create a similar marker yourself in a data store that will outlive that particular VM.

One unanswered question down that path is how that external state would get cleaned up if you were to destroy the VM entirely, since the software running in the VM can't tell whether the system is being shut down in preparation for replacement or being shut down in response to just destroying.